# setInterval does not seem to be working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

This code does not seem to be working. I am trying to create a dynamic list of chat rooms available that updates every 10 seconds. I also want the user to be able to set peraminters to filter what rooms would be shown.
I am using this code, and it does not seem to be working for some reason.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setRooms()
{
    console.log('ok');
    if($('#only').is(':checked'))
    {
     var checked = 1;   
    }
    else 
    {
    var checked = 0;    
    }
    if($('#open').is(':checked'))
    {
     var opened  = 1;   
    }
    else 
    {
    var opened = 0; 
    }
    $.post('backend/outputRooms', {
        fLevel : $('#flevel').val(), 
        sLevel : $('#slevel').val(),
        display : $('display').val(),
        Checked : checked,

        }, 
        function(data)
        {
            $('#text').html(data);
        }); 
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(setRooms(), 10000);
    });
</script>
```

I have ruled out a problem with the backend page, as the console.log('ok') does not seem to be working as well. Any help?

Comment: Are you saying the console.log is not getting hit?  I ran it in jsfiddle and ok is getting printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting quotes around your function:

```
setInterval('setRooms()', 10000);
```

Alternatively change your method to:

```
var setRooms = function()
```

and you can then use:

```
setInterval(setRooms, 10000);
```

Comment: Neither of these is needed.  Just pass the name of the function as shown in Vitaly's answer.

Comment: Yes, they work, but the first is not recommended (not best practice) and the second is not needed since `setRooms` is already a symbol that represents the function.

Answer (score 12):

> setInterval(setRooms, 10000);